# Read file and separate to different lists

Tags: python, csv

below is my CSV dataset.

```
a,d,g

b,e,h

c,f,i
```

I would like to separate these 3 column as `row[0], row[1], and row[2]`. 
And also to make them as 3 different lists.

Here is my code:

```
import csv

file1 = open('....my_path.csv')


Row_0 = [row[0].upper() for row in csv.reader(file1)]
Row_1 = [row[1].upper() for row in csv.reader(file1)]
Row_2 = [row[2].upper() for row in csv.reader(file1)]

print Row_0
print Row_1
print Row_2
```

However, I only can see `Row_0` result from the console. But the `Row_1` and `Row_2` are always showing `[ ]`. Which means I only can see the first row, but not the second and following rows.

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
[]
[]
```

Does anyone can help me to deal with this "simple" issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open` returns an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), which becomes exhausted (no longer usable) after you iterate through it once.  Moreover, each time you do `csv.reader(file1)`, `csv.reader` will try to iterate over the iterator referenced by `file1`. This means that, after the first call, this iterator will become exhausted and all subsequent calls to `csv.reader` will be using an empty iterator.

To do what you want, you would need something like:

```
import csv

file1 = open('....my_path.csv')


Row_0, Row_1, Row_2 = ([row[0].upper(), row[1].upper(), [row[2].upper()]
                       for row in csv.reader(file1))

print Row_0
print Row_1
print Row_2
```

Now, we get all of the data in one read and only iterate over the iterator once.

Also, in case you are wondering, the code I used is known as a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression).  You could also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
Row_0, Row_1, Row_2 = [[row[0].upper(), row[1].upper(), [row[2].upper()]
                       for row in csv.reader(file1)]
```

but I don't see a point in building a list just to throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

You've read through the whole file! check out the file position after your first comprehension,

You could `seek(0)` between comprehensions or just iterate once, or reopen the file as @kdopen stated